# Notification.Icon loading .png and url fine, but not local file

Tags: notifications, icons, desktop-application, electron

I'm more trying to understand this than anything, I am not sure if there is an actual solution.

I am using the Notification API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) and more specifically this is about the icon property in conjunction with Electron.

I am trying to build a custom notification balloon on Mac and Windows. Everything seems to be pretty straight forward and work, besides the icon part.

This is the issue i am facing (I have verified the file paths exist):

option 1, icon.png (works):

```
var myNotificiation = new Notification(
            title, {
                body: message,
                icon: jetpack.path(__dirname, 'assets', 'icon.png')
            });
```

option 2, URL (works):

```
 var myNotificiation = new Notification(
            title, {
                body: message,
                icon: "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1zOS6CtRHjyHhgclhEKRZ_ipCGU2VCthotUjPp7ErPvSnWb6zZ9fNlA"
            });
```

option 3, local html file (doesn't work):

```
var myNotificiation = new Notification(
            title, {
                body: message,
                icon: jetpack.path(__dirname, 'services', 'icon.html')
            });
```

For consistency, this is the content of the icon.html page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVUJB.jpg

Question:

Why does the image of the local file jetpack.path(__dirname, 'services', 'icon.html') not populate the icon part of the notification, but the URL image does show up in that same spot?

Any help would be appreciated. I hope its just something simply wrong in my HTML page, but I couldn't find anything wrong yet.

Comment: `icon.html` is not an image, why are you trying to use it as an icon?

Comment: Indeed it isnt an image, but so is the URL. Thats why i am so confused...Reason i want to use HTML instead of an image is so that i can create a custom 'icon' for each notification, without having to have all icons created beforehand. In this example the icon is a circle with a letter, but the background color of the circle changes with each customer, and the letter changes with each user...

Comment: The URL links directly to an image, not an html document, which is consistent with the description of the icon parameter: `The icon read-only property of the Notification interface contains the URL of an icon.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vadim Macagon:

The URL links directly to an image, not an html document, which is consistent with the description of the icon parameter: The icon read-only property of the Notification interface contains the URL of an icon.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (source:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1025#issue-54722118)

```js
new Notification({ 
  title: "Message", 
  body: msg,
  icon:'electronImages/hi.png'
}).show()
```

[image: check example here]